# Change radio button value with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two radio buttons:

```
 <input type="radio" name="editList" id="prov" value="Admin">Admin
 <input type="radio" name="editList" id="user" value="User">User
```

I want to change values with javascript, and I try as:

```
var typeu= $('input[type=radio][name=editList]').val();

if (typeu=== "Admin") {
     typeu= typeu.val() === "A";
} else if (typeu === 'User') {
    typeu= typeu.val() === "U";
```

But I get issue:

Uncaught TypeError: typeu.val is not a function

Can someone help me please?

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Specifically, what is `tipoResponsable`, and how are you using `typeu` after you attempt to assign the new value to it?

Comment: You are trying to call `.val()` on `typeu` which is `$('input[type=radio][name=editList]').val()`, that won't work.

Comment: `typeu` is a string, not an object.

Comment: So I need to call `$('input[type=radio][name=editList]').val();` in each if? @ShanevandenBogaard

Comment: where is your `<input type="radio" name="editList" />` ?

Comment: No, you could define a reference to the element and call the `val()` statement on that reference. var $elem = $('input[...]); if ($elem.val() === 'Admin') { ... }

Comment: `let typeu = $('input[name=editList][type=radio]:selected').val().substring(0,1);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
var typeu = $('input[type=radio][name=editList]');

$.each(typeu, function(i, v) {
  if ($(v).val() === "Admin") {
    $(v).val("A");
  } else if ($(v).val() === 'User') {
    $(v).val("U");
  }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/za61z3vx/

First line, you get all the inputs that match `type=radio` and `name=editList`. Since there's more than one it'll be an array, so you need iterate through it.

Answer (score 0):

To check radio button by javascript you should use "prop" function

```
 $('#prov').prop('checked', true );
 // or $('#prov').prop('checked', false );
```

To GET checked prop u should use:

```
 $('#prov').prop('checked');
```

From your code:

```
 var typeu= $('input[type=radio][name=editList]');
 typeu.each( radio => { 
   const $rb = $(radio);
   console.log( $rb.val(), $rb.prop('checked') ) 
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`val(function)`](http://api.jquery.com/val/#val-function)

```js
var radioValues = {
   'Admin':'A',
   'User':'U'
};

$('#prov, #user').val(function(_, existingValue){
   // if current value matches keys in object, will return new value
   // if not a match will return existing value
   return radioValues[this.value] || existingValue;
})
// log updated values for this demo
.each(function(){
   console.log(this.id, 'value is', this.value)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="editList" id="prov" value="Admin">Admin
 <input type="radio" name="editList" id="user" value="User">User
```

---

Note that your attempt will only return value of the first element. You need to loop over them and deal with each instance